# Как использовать готовое решение на Delphi в С/С++ проекте?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, winapi

Пишу Win32 программу на C/C++ (вообще на С, но поддерживается ООП). По сути даже не пишу, а склеиваю готовые решения с GitHub (малый опыт работы с Win32). Нужна одна функциональность, которую долго и тяжело писать. Нашла просто идеальное решение (кроссархитектурное (подгоняется под архитектуру ЦП), кросс-версионное (или как назвать то, что работает от Windows Vista до Windows 10)). По сути, решение очень гибкое и просто замечательно работает, ибо уже потестила его. Проблема в том, что это решение написано на Delphi. Аналогов на C/C++ не нашла. Кода там оочень много, к тому же хотя Delphi имеет очень понятный синтаксис, на С мне тяжело перевести код. К тому же очень много переводить. Использовала Delphi2Cpp, но скептически отношусь к таким приложениям. К тому же оно неправильно интерпретировало код. Пыталась использовать RAD Studio, которое якобы позволяет использовать в одном проекте C++ и Delphi. Но возникли некоторые проблемы с этой IDE. Да и после Visual Studio 2017 тяжело в ней работать. Планирую всё-таки скомпилировать этот Delphi-проект в .exe и вшить его в своё приложение. Но немного почитав о "вшитии" .exe в .exe понимаю, что это может нарушить стабильность моей программы. Да и решение так себе. Можете что-то посоветовать в решении данной проблемы?

Comment: А нельзя Delphi проложение скомпилировать в dll, а в C программе грузить эту длл и через экспортные функцие как-то управлять этим приложением. А что ваша C программа по сути должна делать? Только запускать Delphi приложение?

Comment: @Unick о Вашем варианте тоже думала, но нужно чтобы был один исполняемый файл без каких-либо зависимостей. Знаю, можно dll вшить в exe. В принципе, идея неплохая. Попробую.
По поводу "А что ваша C программа по сути должна делать? Только запускать Delphi приложение?". Нет, там большая функциональность. Писала ведь "По сути даже не пишу, а склеиваю готовые решения с GitHub". Просто нужносложное  решение, которое нашла только на Delphi.

Comment: увы, делфи не умеет делать статические либы. Вшивание dll в ехе - плохая идея, т.к. dll в любом случае придется выгружать на диск, чтобы процесс смог нормально загрузить библиотеку через LoadLibrary или тянуть в проект еще одну зависимость для загрузки из памяти. Также возможно вы плохо искали, расскажите, что вам надо и мы можем помочь найти/подсказать как реализовать нужное решение на с/с++

Comment: "вшитие" - какой-то мутный термин, если тут имеется ввиду "статически прилинковать", то ответ будет: нет, Delphi не выдает совместимых объектных файлов.

Comment: @goldstar_labs нужно сделать возможность мультиконекта к RD (remote desktop). Делать патч файла termsrv.dll не вариант, ибо после обновления ОС файл обновится и возмодность мультиконекта пропадёт. Хочу создать прослойку между менеджером управления службами (SCM- Service Control Manager) и службой терминалов (Terminal Services), что позволит включить не только поддержку нескольких одновременных RDP сессий, но и активировать поддержку RDP Host на домашних редакциях Windows 10.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Этот подход не вносит никаких изменений в файл termsrv.dll, просто подгружая termsrv с изменёнными параметрами. Вот решение, которое нашла https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap . И да, повторюсь: то, что я здесь описала - это только одна из функциональностей приложения.

Comment: его можно запустить отдельным модулем system(name.exe); [ссылка](https://youtu.be/4NVYglsNjPM?t=23m37s) -- в этой секунде автор видео на последней строке написал команду, **запускающую приложение(.exe)**

Comment: @J.Huxley, я посмотрел код проекта rdpwrap, он может быть малой кровью переведен на с++. Конечно это время, но как вариант решения проблемы.

Comment: @goldstar_labs я тоже думаю и уже начала вручную переводить его.

Comment: Как вариант можно собрать delphi dll, а потом вшить её как ресурс. При старте извлекать ресурс и подгружать динамически.

Comment: Смотрели видео от Embarcadero о том как это работает (Delphi и C++ в одном проекте)? https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/mixing-delphi-and-c

Comment: @kot-da-vinci да, смотрела первым делом. Проблема в том, что скачала с официального сайта последнюю версию RAD Studio (10.2); выбрала испытательный период. В вариантах билда было только x32, хотя у меня ОС x64.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci загуглила "RAD Studio build x64" илои что-то подобное (может у кого была эта проблема), но в итоге никто не писал о подобной проблеме и обычно выдавало на документацию IDE. В документации демонстрируется, что x64 уже есть в Target Platform for compilation. У меня в настройках компилятора (билдера) кобмобокс выдаёт только x32. Но это не единственная проблема, с которой столкнулась.

Comment: @J.Huxley, компилятор по x64 выбирается в компонентах при установке. По умолчанию он выбран, возможно это зависит типа лицензии. Если компилятор установлен, то, возможно, вам нужно вручную добавить Target Platform в свой проект. А может его нет для плюсов? Для проекта на Delphi можете добавить платформу под х64?